# Crontab not running PHP script, despite log

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, permissions, cron

I log into my AWS server as ec2-user, but I try to have everything run as root, so I manage my crontab with the `sudo crontab -e` command.  This is what is in it:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/a*****/cron/cron.php
* * * * * php /var/www/html/d*****/cron/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/k*****/cron/cron.php
* * * * * php /var/www/html/l*****/cron/cron.php
```

The `/var/www/html/k*****/cron/cron.php` script looks like the following:

```
<?php
include_once('../functions.php');
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");


// ==============================================

$content = file_get_contents("output.txt");

file_put_contents("output.txt", date('j M Y \a\t g:ia').
                  "\n\n---------------------\n".$content);

// ==============================================

performScheduledJobs();
```

The other `cron.php` files in the `sudo crontab -e` view all look identical, except without the bit between the `// =====` marks.

Since these scripts are supposed to run every minute (per the `sudo crontab -e` settings, with the five spaced asterisk marks `* * * * *`), I would expect the `output.txt` to have the current timestamp (in UTC) being printed every minute.  Instead, it only contains the (UTC) timestamp of every time the script is run *manually* using the following command:

`sudo php cron.php`

That command (from within the `/var/www/html/k*****/cron/` directory, of course) works 100% successfully.

Of course, my instinct is that the `cron.php` file isn't even being attempted to be run, but when I `sudo vi /var/log/cron` I see the following:

```
Mar 27 21:51:01 ip-172-***-***-184 CROND[32032]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/a*****/cron/cron.php)
Mar 27 21:51:01 ip-172-***-***-184 CROND[32033]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/d*****/cron/cron.php)
Mar 27 21:51:01 ip-172-***-***-184 CROND[32035]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/k*****/cron/cron.php)
Mar 27 21:51:01 ip-172-***-***-184 CROND[32034]: (root) CMD (php /var/www/html/l*****/cron/cron.php)
```

As I said **running the `sudo php cron.php` command works**, so whatever is wrong is likely with my crontab configuration.

Anyone have and ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is not in the path when running in crond. You need to specify the full path to the php executable. You can find what this is by running `which php`

This should output the full path to the php binary called when you run `php cron.php` and will be something like `/usr/bin/php` If you replace `php` with this in your crontab it should run fine.